# How to get notified when moving back from React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have this component. How to get notified when component unmounts or disappears?

```
function EventTime(props) {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const eventTime = findEventTime(match.params.eventTimeId);
  const eventTimeId = match.params.eventTimeId;
  const pageId = getId(undefined, eventTimeId, true, false);
  const eventId = getId(undefined, eventTimeId, false, true);
  const [
    enableSellingTicketForEventTime,
    setEnableSellingTicketForEventTime
  ] = useState(eventTime.enableSellingTicketForEventTime);
  const [additionalNotesOnMyTicket, setAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket] = useState(
    ""
  );

  const changeAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket = event => {
    setAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSwitchItem = () => {
    setEnableSellingTicketForEventTime(!enableSellingTicketForEventTime);
  };

  const updateAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket = () => {
    update({
      pageId,
      eventId,
      eventTimeId,
      additionalNotesOnMyTicket
    }).then(data => {
      const managedPages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("managedPages"));
      const index = managedPages.findIndex(
        managedPage => managedPage.id === pageId
      );
      managedPages[index].events[eventId].eventTimes[
        eventTimeId
      ].additionalNotesOnMyTicket = additionalNotesOnMyTicket;
      localStorage.setItem("managedPages", JSON.stringify(managedPages));
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("managedPages")));
    });
  };

  console.log(eventTime);
  return (
    <div>
      <List>
        {page().permission === "admin" && (
          <Link
            to={`/eventTimeLocationSelector/${match.params.eventTimeId}`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
          >
            <NavigationItem
              primary="Location"
              secondary={
                eventTime.locationId
                  ? getLocationName(eventTime.locationId)
                  : ""
              }
            />
          </Link>
        )}
        {page().permission === "admin" && page().auditoriums && (
          <Link
            to={`/eventTimeAuditoriumSelector/${match.params.eventTimeId}`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
          >
            <NavigationItem
              primary="Auditorium"
              secondary={
                eventTime.auditoriumId
                  ? getAuditoriumName(eventTime.auditoriumId)
                  : ""
              }
            />
          </Link>
        )}
        {page().permission !== "validateTicket" && (
          <SwitchItem
            primary="Enable selling ticket for event time"
            checked={enableSellingTicketForEventTime}
            change={handleSwitchItem}
            default={false}
          />
        )}
        <Link
          to={`/eventTimeTransactions/${match.params.eventTimeId}`}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
        >
          <NavigationItem primary="Sold tickets" />
        </Link>
        <TextFieldItem
          primary="Additional notes on my ticket"
          value={additionalNotesOnMyTicket}
          onChange={changeAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket}
          onBlur={updateAdditionalNotesOnMyTicket}
        />
      </List>
      {page().permission !== "validateTicket" &&
        page().permission !== "teacher" && (
          <Box style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }} mr={2}>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
              Add person
            </Button>
          </Box>
        )}
```

Comment: componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
}
Hook equivalent of above code will be as follows

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {});

  // returned function will be called on component unmount 
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
  }
}, [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using hooks you can use `useEffect` hook.

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react';
```

Now, inside you component;

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // Do something here when component unmounts
  }
}, [])
```

Check more about `useEffect` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You can use like this.

Comment: Hi! The strange is that if I put in `useEffect` method and put in a break point in the method,  `useEffect` will not get called if i.e. I press back button in the browser.

Comment: It will not work in that manner. useEffect only runs if you unmount's component through your code.

Comment: So I need to use`window.addEventListener` and `window.removeEventListener` in `useEffect`?

Comment: yeah you can do that.
You can listen for `beforeunload ` on closing tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function to be called when the component unmounts as the `useEffect()`'s hook return value. Check out this: [useEffect hook official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)